# Magento 2 : how to show custom shipping address in email template?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates

I am trying to send & show custom shipping address on email template

here is the code

```
            $ship_country_id = "US";
            $ship_region_id = "CA";
            $ship_region = "12";
            $ship_street = "780 N. Yup Tea";
            $ship_city = "Los Angeles, California";
            $ship_postcode = "9001";

                $ship_firstName = $email_pickup_data['pickupName'];
                $ship_lastName = "";
                $ship_telephone   = $email_pickup_data['pickupPhone'];
                $sales_la_order_address_ship = array(
                    'region_id' => $ship_region_id,
                    'region' => $ship_region,
                    'postcode' => $ship_postcode,
                    'street' => $ship_street,
                    'city' => $ship_city,
                    'telephone' => $ship_telephone,
                    'country_id' => $ship_country_id,
                    'address_type' => 'shipping',
                    'firstname' => $ship_firstName,
                    'lastname' => $ship_lastName,
                    'middlename' => "",
                    'email' => "",
                    'fax' => "",
                    'status' => 0,
                    'pickupPhone' =>$email_pickup_data['pickupPhone']
                );  

            $transport['la_pickup_address'] = $sales_la_order_address_ship;
            $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);
```

But in email template when i use {{ var la_pickup_address }} it shows error

Any thoughts on this ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

in variable **$sales_la_order_address_ship** set HTML output that you want to display in email instead of array.

Comment: Hello, can you update answer ? I am not much sure how magento default does that i need to do the same as default magento code. 
Any thoughts how it can be done ?